# Win 8 apps (js, html , css, winrt) scroll

Tags: javascript, windows-8, scroll

I'm trying to porting a simple webapp (html js css) to a windows 8 javascript app. The original app has a empty html table, and i dynamically add rows to it. in the browser, it is fine, because even if the table get large, the scroll provide navigation. in the windows 8 apps, the table is generated, but the scrow doesn't appears,

how to provide navigation to the app over the html table dynamically created by the .js ?

thanks !

Comment: does the constraining element have overflow set correctly?

Comment: Any luck solving this?